# Hive table dynamic partition load using Sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have a MySQL table called `dept` which I load to Hive EXTERNAL table `dept` table as incremental append check-column last-value based on a time stamp column `ts`.

This is working fine and now I want to add dynamic partition to my hive table `dept` based on `dept_name` and `ts` columns.

I know that I can create table dynamic partition outside sqoop but need help in loading data to dynamic partitions. I saw one example using `--hive-partition-key` & `--hive-partition-value`  but there the value is hard coded. Without hard coding the hive-partition-values, can I load data automatically to corresponding partitions using SQOOP say (dept1,timestamp1/dept1,timestamp2..etc) and (dept2,timestamp1/dept2,timestamp2...etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load the data from the external table you have created into the dynamic partitioned table without hardcoding the partitioned values.

Assuming that you already have your external table `externalDept` with the values and also that you have created your partitioned table `dept`, you could use something like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dept 
PARTITION (dept_name, ts)
SELECT ..., ed.dept_name, ed.ts
FROM externalDept ed
```

It's not part of your question, but you could also mix both static and dynamic partitions. For instance, if you wanted to specify a dynamic value for the `timestamp` but a static value for the `dept`, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dept 
PARTITION (dept_name = 'Math', ts)
SELECT ..., ed.dept_name, ed.ts
FROM externalDept ed
WHERE ed.dept_name = 'Math'
```

Comment: Thank you Jaime.My requirement is to move all current MySQL table data to Hive table, then based on daily insert/update happening in MySQL table, I want to load all such records to HIVE tables.So for history load,as you mentioned, I can first move all MySQL data to HIVE external table and then load to dynamic partitioned table based on dept_name and ts.For Incremental loads,what is the best approach ?

Comment: Up to my knowedge, there isn't any "simple and direct" way to do this. Currently, Sqoop does not support importing into dynamic partitions (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-312), so I would follow an approach like this one (https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.0/bk_dataintegration/content/incrementally-updating-hive-table-with-sqoop-and-ext-table.html), in which on daily basis, you could load the "new" data into an external table (just as with the initial load), and then, use an `INSERT` into your Hive table (without the `OVERWRITE`).

Comment: Thanks.I have 50 distinct department names.That is why I planned to partition based on department name and time stamp.I always use dept name in WHERE clause to do query.Do you think my partitioning approach is fine or any better approach ? Suppose I have employee id also part of this record which is string(not integer), would it be better to add bucketing also on employee id column ? any such example you can help with ?

Comment: Regarding your first question, I think it's fine assuming that your rows are more or less evenly distributed among the different 50 departments. So it depends on the way that your partition keys are going to "split" the data (symmetrically or asymmetrically), but the `dept` partition approach sound fine. As for the second question, I don't see anything wrong to adding a bucketed level based on employee_id, up to my knowledge, it's one of the most "typical" ways to do it.

Comment: This (http://hadooptutorial.info/bucketing-in-hive/#Inserting_data_Into_Bucketed_Tables) may be helpful.